# How can I call docker API from container (Docker for Mac)

Tags: docker

First I mounted docker.sock from mac to container.
And I want to call API from container like

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http:/v1.30/containers/xxxxx/restart?t=5
```

However
    `curl: option --unix-socket: is unknown` 
such error occurred.

How can I mange it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the version of curl you are running. The `--unix-socket` option was added in version `7.40`.  If you have an older version, you will need to upgrade.

Other options are to write a script in the language of your choice that uses the Docker SDK.  You can see the list of supported languages here `https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdks`

Finally, you can install the docker binary into the container.  If you are basing the container on one of the linux distribution (ubuntu, alpine), you can install the package.  Or you can map the docker binary from the host into the container `-v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker`.  Note, if you map in the binary from the host, make sure the user/group access controls are setup properly as the users/groups in a container are different than on the host.

Hope this help